# Multiple Column SUM with Join table - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a two tables `winners` and `check_winners`.

### winners:

> ```
> id     check_winner_id      username     win_number ....
>  1                   1           xxx              1
>  2                   2           xxx              1
>  3                   3           yyy              1
>  4                   4           yyy              1
> ```

### check_winners:

> ```
> id       user_id      chance_of_win....
>  1             1                  1
>  2             1                  1
>  3             2                  1
>  4             2                  1
>  5             2                  1
>  6             2                  1
>  7             2                  1
>  8             2                  1
> ```

Now i want to `join` two tables and want to sum `chance_of_win` column and `win_number` column group by `username`. I have tried an way but its not give exactly result for sum of `win_number`. How can i achieve this?

```
$winners = DB::table('winners')
            ->groupBy('winners.username')
            ->leftJoin('check_winners', 'winners.id', '=', 'check_winners.user_id')
            ->selectRaw('*, sum(check_winners.chance_of_win) as chance_sum, sum(winners.win_number) as win_sum')         
dd($winners);
```

with this i get output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#241 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"check_winner_id": 1
    +"username": "xxx"
    +"chance_sum": "2"
    +"win_sum": "2"
  }
  1 => {#242 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"check_winner_id": 2
    +"username": "yyy"
    +"chance_sum": "6"
    +"win_sum": "6"
  }
]
```

but `win_sum` should be `2` for both `array`. Where i did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with distinct('winners.username') instead of groupBy(''winners.username')

Comment: if i use `distinct('winners.username')` then i get one array with `win_sum 10` and `chance_sum 2`

Comment: I have added my answer please check its work or not

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd  with your solution i get, first `array` with value `chance_sum` and `win_sum` both `8`. and second `array` `chance_sum null` and `win_sum 2`.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud see your "xxx" username belongs to two user_id 1,2 as per your leftjoin and when you group by then your winners table id 2 will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$winners = DB::table('winners')
            ->leftJoin('check_winners', 'winners.id', '=', 'check_winners.user_id')
            ->selectRaw('*, sum(check_winners.chance_of_win) as chance_sum, sum(winners.win_number) as win_sum')
            ->groupBy('winners.username')       
dd($winners);
```

**Updated answer**

```
$winners = DB::table('winners')
            ->select('*', DB::raw("SUM(check_winners.chance_of_win) as chance_sum"), DB::raw("SUM(winners.win_number) as win_sum"))
            ->leftJoin('check_winners', 'winners.id', '=', 'check_winners.user_id')
            ->groupBy('winners.username')
```

Comment: with this solution i get. first `array` with value `chance_sum` and `win_sum` both `8`. and second `array` `chance_sum null` and `win_sum 2`.

Comment: same thing happened. second array chance_sum is null.